# Find the origin of a rectangle over the circumference of a circle

Tags: geometry, circles

I am trying to draw a rectangle over the circumference of a circle in iOS. I thought the question is related to geometrics, so I post this here.

I can't explain it in english, so I have drawn a picture which is below.

[image]

I have to find the position of the red dot here.

I have the following details:

1. Angle
2. Size of the square
3. Radius of the Circle

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you drew here, you can write the polar coordinates of the red dot as $$\left(\sqrt{\left(R-\frac{r}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{r}{2}\right)^2}, \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{r}{2R-r}\right)\right)$$
if $\ r$ is the length of a side on the square, and $R$ is the radius of the circle.